# Running Management command with celery?

Tags: django, heroku, redis, celery

I have never used Celery before and am trying to configure it correctly. I am using redis as the broker and hosting on heroku. This is my first time trying to run asynchronous tasks and I'm struggling. I have a Management command that I would like to run periodically.

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os 
import celery
from celery import Celery
import django
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'coffee.settings')
app = Celery('coffee')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace = 'CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind= True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add-every-30-seconds':{
        'task': 'inventory.tasks.boarshead',
        'schedule' : 30.0,
        'args' : ()
    },
}
```

settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
         "LOCATION": os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'),
    }
}
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
import celery
import time
from django.core import management

@celery.task
def boarshead():
    try:
        print("in celery module")
        """Boarshead expired sessions by using Django Management Command."""
        management.call_command("clearsessions", verbosity=0)
        CreateBoarsHeadList.py
        return "success"

    except:
        print(e)
```

**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app as celery_app
```

procfile

```
worker: celery worker --app=tasks.inventory.app
```

Answer (score 0):

On Celery+Rabbit (and REDIS, not used as backend for years) you will need a proc file for the "web" (Django) and one for the worker, did not see listed. Worker / dyno allocation allows use and access to the manage functionality. Here is the procfile from one of my apps:

`web: gunicorn SOME_APP.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery worker -A QUEUE_APP_NAME -l info  --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat`

`QUEUE_APP_NAME` is the name of a module (app) where I have all my Celery work and code.  `worker` is called via Procfile in the `QUEUE_APP_NAME` module (dir), similar code to your Celery file.  May not solve you, but getting Celery working is a slow battle.